# Is there a way to typecast a whole list of Big Decimals to list of Long values

Tags: java, long-integer, bigdecimal

If I have a `List` of `BigDecimal` objects, is it possible to typecast the whole list to a `List` of `Long` values without having to iterate over every `BigDecimal` object?

Comment: If you don't want to iterate over the entire list, how do you plan on getting the values from the entire list?  Also, the cast probably wouldn't work, but there's a way to get the long value from those objects.

Comment: Even if you use java stream api available since Java 8, you need to iterate through the elements of the collection.

Comment: @Makoto I will iterate over it later but I dont want to do it twice. I was not too optimistic about finding a solution, I guess I will have to do longValue() on each object.

Comment: You can return a LongStream though, so that if the caller is only iterating over the first 10 elements of the stream, only the first 10 will be transformed to long values: a Stream is lazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to iterate one way or another. If you want to "hide" the iteration, you can use a stream:

```
List<Long> longs = bigs.stream().map(BigDecimal::longValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But there will still be an iteration in the background.

You mention that you don't want to iterate twice - you could save the stream of longs for later use:

```
LongStream longs = bigs.stream().mapToLong(BigDecimal::longValue);
```

And apply additional operations on that stream before collecting the results.

Comment: Saving a stream for later use will only work once: once a stream has been consumed, it can't be reused.

Comment: @assylias this looks like something I can work with.. Thanks alot

Comment: @JBNizet There is a way to "reuse" streams by putting them in a generator function.

Answer (score 0):

Without Java 8 streams, you can use guava transform:

```
private List<Long> convertToLongList(List<BigDecimal> bigDecimalList) {
    return Lists.transform(bigDecimalList, new Function<BigDecimal, Long>() {
        public Long apply(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
            return bigDecimal.longValue();
        }
    });
}
```